# How to apply OAuth signature to Masterpass API Partner wallet Services?

Tags: java, api, mastercard

I'm trying to integrate masterpass Api Partner wallet, but in there is no exact documentation about the way to apply the OAuth signature. Can you please help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

The way I used to apply the signature was:

I include the  masterpass merchant api, available in maven repository:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mastercard.masterpass.merchant</groupId>
        <artifactId>mastercard-masterpass-merchant</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then you need to load the ApiConfig and set the private key, the public key, the Host point, and the environment.

```
ApiConfig apiConfig = null;
try {
apiConfig = new ApiConfigBuilder()
  .consumerKey(MASTERPASS_CONSUMER_KEY)
  .privateKey(MASTERPASS_PRIVATE_KEY)
  .hostUrl(MASTERPASS_HOST)
  .name(MASTERPASSS_ENVIRONMENT).build();
} catch (Exception e) {
  logger.error("[Error]Error loading masterpass Api Config: {}", e.getMessage());
}
```

After you configure these, now you can call the ApiClient form masterpass library:

```
ApiClient client = new ApiClient(apiConf);

ServiceRequest<?> request = new ServiceRequest<>();

request.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
request.requestBody(shippingAddressRequest);

ShippingAddressVerificationResponse response = null;
try {
  response = client.call(masterpassEndpoint, request, HttpMethod.POST , ShippingAddressVerificationResponse.class);
} catch (Exception e) {
  logger.error("[Error]ShippingAddressVerificationResponse]"+
  "Error: There was an exception validating the shipping address: {}", e.getMessage() , e);
}
```